# What is the Big O complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I need help understanding how to breakdown this function so I can know how to get to the answer of the questions being asked? I know the order of growth but still have some doubts about how to read this on an algorithm?

What is the big O complexity of the following function?

```
def complexity(n):
  k = 0
  for i in range(2, n):
    for j in range(n, 2*n):
      k= k+1
```

- (a) complexity1: O(n<sup>3</sup>)
- (b) complexity1: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- (c) complexity1: O(n)
- (d) complexity1: O(nlog<sub>n</sub>)
- (e) None of the above

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you paste code into your question, please make sure that it's properly formatted. It's unreadable at the moment. Furthermore, please make an effort to solve this homework yourself. This exercise is so simple that you should be able to do it yourself if you have looked at a couple of examples.

Comment: Read this carefully and attempt to solve the question yourself after that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the summation

[image]

you can see that the number of steps performed are exactly `(n-2)*n`.
Thus, the time complexity `T(n) = O(n^2)`.

Practical example:

```
>>> complexity(5)
15
>>> complexity(10)
80
>>> complexity(20)
360
```